# Parsing nested array in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a nested object in my code. I am trying to list every node name in the list on to a html table

```
$scope.data = {
    "name": "A",
    "children": [{
      "name": "A1",
      "children": [{
        "name": "A2",
        "children": [{
          "name": "A3",
          "children": []
        }, {
          "name": "B",
          "children": []
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "C",
      "children": [{
        "name": "C1",
        "children": []
      }]
    }]
  }
```

I am trying to parse this list and add all the name and children.name into one list called $scope.result and print the values using this list on the HTML side 
On the HTML side of the code I have the following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="val in result">
      <td>{{val}}</td>
</tr>
```

I might need to use forEach but I am having some trouble figuring it out.

My output needs to look something like this

```
A
A1
A2
A3
B
C
C1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion here to create a flat array for the ng repeat. If each object has children - then pass each child back through the function to push the name value into the new array.

Note that I have removed the $scope references for this snippet in here but you would then be able to iterate over the flattened array with an ng-repeat.

```js
data = {
    "name": "A",
    "children": [{
      "name": "A1",
      "children": [{
        "name": "A2",
        "children": [{
          "name": "A3",
          "children": []
        }, {
          "name": "B",
          "children": []
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "C",
      "children": [{
        "name": "C1",
        "children": []
      }]
    }]
  }
  
  var result = [];
  
  createArr(data);
  
  function createArr(obj) {
    result.push(obj.name);

      if(obj.children){
        obj.children.forEach(function(child){
          createArr(child)
        })
      }
  }
  
  console.log(result); // gives ["A","A1","A2","A3","B","C","C1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at my codePen example.

```
`https://codepen.io/Milos44/pen/WNewXEL`
```

Comment: Pardon my text formatting, still new to commenting on stack... :)